# How to stop sound and go back to idle animation on movement in ue4

Tags: animation, game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

so I'm making Emotes for my game and I need it so if the player moves at all it cancels the Animation and the Sound, does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code in ThirdPersonCharacter for the emote: 
[image: ThirdPersonCharacter]

I also need it so once the B key is pressed you can't press it again until you move. Without this you can spam the key and the sound goes crazy.

Thanks everyone!

P.S. The emote and sound loops, the sound is playing a cue

Comment: did you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily friend , you need to attach an audio component to your actor so that you have a reference to play it and stop it when your player starts to move or is standing idle, I recommend binding a function to where your player moves to stop the sound . The audio component has a stop function . You can also create a function to choose which sound should the audio component plays.

Now as for your second problem of sound going crazy a do once with delay node back to complete should do the trick , nonetheless there is also an input delay node which I forgot , YAAAAAAY time to learn new nodes!

I hope it helps . Keep on working :).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're using the animations directly from the asset when, in fact, this is a perfect opportunity to use a [Montage](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Animation/AnimMontage) and blend the emote into the character.

If you detect movement input you can then cancel the whole thing. To stop the sound, you'll need to save a reference to the spawned SpawnSound2D in a variable. From there, a simple **Stop** node will do the trick. I'd probably leave the Montage running until it finishes to avoid unnatural character animations but if you *truly* need to stop the animation as well, use a **Stop Anim Montage** node

Be careful, though, sudden disruption of player feedback can feel clunky.